# Why does the pointer to method dereference operator in C++ have such low priority?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The pointer to member dereference operator (`.*` and `->*`) in C++ is of operator precedence 4, while the function call operator is of precedence 2. This pretty much guarantees that parenthesis will be required:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int b;

    int func1( int a ) { return a+b+1; }
    int func2( int a ) { return 2*a+b; }
};

int main() {
    A a;

    a.b = 3;

    int (A::*ptr)(int);

    ptr = &A::func1;
    std::cout<<
            (a.*ptr) // <- these parenthesis
                ( 2 ) << "\n";
}
```

It seems to me that defining `.*` as priority 2 would (with left to right associativity) negate the need of the parenthesis with no obvious ill side effects.

What was the reason for choosing this priority?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know for sure, but remember that the following code is valid:

```
const double x = 2.*3 + 4; // (2.0 * 3) + 4
```

It's possible that making `.*` have different precedence would have unacceptably complicated the tokenisation stage.

Whatever the reason, it's been this way since the 1980s, and CFront 2.0 ([doc](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_2.0/doc/ProductReferenceManual.pdf), page 22). Unfortunately no explicit rationale was given at that time, nor in any other [historical document](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/index.html#std_docs) that I can find.

Comment: I don't get this answer. The precedence of the `.*` token is not determined by its tokenization, as those happen in different phases of compilation. (Tokenization already happens in the preprocessing phase)

Comment: @MSalters I was hypothesising that the potential ambiguity between `.` `.*` as two tokens and `.*` as one token may have led to deliberately choosing this precedence to keep the resulting machinery as simple to resolve as possible. But, now that I think about it, there's no ambiguity because `<digit>.` is always going to be a floating-point literal before the `*` is even encountered. So, er, yeah. Lol.

Comment: Maybe let's call this a case study in how some people will upvote _anything_, and move on? ;)

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'm building my own language. One of things I am planning is fixing the operator precedence errors that C and C++ made (https://github.com/Practical/practical-sa/wiki/Operators). I am interested in knowing whether I'm missing something in claiming this is a mistake.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit BTW, I also upvoted it. It doesn't exactly answer my question, but it's the best effort given so far :-). I've now sent an email to Bjarne Strastrup, we'll see if it wields an answer.

Comment: Hm, I always considered bitwise and/or having lower precedence than comparison operators a weakness, too... Naturally, one would mask some bits out and compare the result to something given, so not needing parentheses for would be nice. However, if you *did* change that, you're new language would be in conflict to what people know from other languages (C++, C, C#, Java, ...). So would changing that really be a good idea? The issue might be similar with the operators in question, altough, admitted, only one other language is affected...

Comment: @ShacharShemesh A good reason to ask! And emailing Bjarne makes sense here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit already did a few hours ago. Took me over 10 minutes to find his email address, and I did go through his web page that warns that he does answer his mail..... eventually. It's a good thing I am still at least months from needing those operators for Practical.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Oh yeah I got that you already did, just saying it was a good idea :) There are also C++ mailing lists you could try - just of committee peeps on there. https://isocpp.org/std/forums

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried the forums as well. Thank you. https://lists.isocpp.org/std-discussion/2019/06/0059.php

Comment: @Aconcagua sadly, this discussion exceeds the scope of what comments here allow. If you look at the list of opertors for Practical, you'll see that I, indeed, fixed that particular deficiency. In brief, I think uses of bitwise ops today either use explicit parenthesis or are bugs, so I don't think the breakage will be great.

Comment: By the way, thank you for not calling it "the ternary operator" *\*shudder\**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd think you'd thank me more for actually not having it :-). It's all marketing anyways. I do have an operator called "the safe cast operator", which is, arguably, just as bad a name.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Perhaps :P

Comment: @ShacharShemesh You say you can use `if` as an expression which tbh sounds like it's ultimately just different syntax for the conditional op (bit like Python's), but w/evs ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194992/discussion-between-shachar-shemesh-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

Consider data members:

```
struct A
{
    int X;
    int* pointer;
};

int main()
{
  int A::*ptr_i;
  ptr_i = &A::X;
  a.*ptr_i = 10;  // Not needed

  int T;
  a.pointer = &T;
  *a.pointer = 20; // Not needed

  int* A::*ptr_ip;
  ptr_ip = &A::pointer;
  *(a.*ptr_ip) = 10;  //  NEEDDED

  int V;
  a.*ptr_ip = &V;
  *(a.*ptr_ip) = 20; // Modifies V, NEEDED

  // Goes interesting..
  A* ap = &a;
  ap->*ptr_ip = &V;
 *(ap->*ptr_ip) = 100;
}
```

I would say this is simplified. If we add more complicated function pointers, then it becomes more clumsy, and hence such precedence rules are needed.

Comment: If `.*` was priority 2 as the poster is suggesting, the parentheses wouldn't be needed in both those cases.